# Program doesn't run completely

Tags: c

I have a program I'm trying to run. it compiles but doesn't run as expected (it runs partially only):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

char play;
char choice;
char answer;

printf("Welcome to Two doors.\n");
printf("Would you like to play? (y/n): ");
scanf("%c", &play);

if (play == 'y') {

    printf("\nYou are a prisoner in a room with 2 doors and 2 guards.\n");
    printf("One of the doors will guide you to freedom and behind the other is a hangman --you don't know which is which.\n");
    printf("One of the guards always tells the truth and the other always lies. You don't know which one is the truth-teller or the liar either.\n");
    printf("You have to choose and open one of these doors, but you can only ask a single question to one of the guards.\n");
    printf("What do you ask so you can pick the door to freedom?\n\n");
    printf("\t1.Ask the truth-guard to point to the door of doom.\n");
    printf("\t2.Ask the liar-guard to point to the door of doom.\n");
    printf("\t3.Doesn't matter which one you pick.\n");
    scanf("%c", &choice);

    char answer = "No matter which one you choose the guards both tell you which door leads to death, and therefore you can pick the other door.\n";
    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            printf("%c", answer);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("%c", answer);
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("%c", answer);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

return 1;
}
```

It seems like I'm unable to have the code to run in its entirety. Here is what I get when running it after entering 'y' to the question:

```
Welcome to Two doors.
Would you like to play? (y/n): y

You are a prisoner in a room with 2 doors and 2 guards.
One of the doors will guide you to freedom and behind the other is a hangman --you don't know which is which.
One of the guards always tells the truth and the other always lies. You don't know which one is the truth-teller or the liar either.
You have to choose and open one of these doors, but you can only ask a single question to one of the guards.
What do you ask so you can pick the door to freedom?

    1.Ask the truth-guard to point to the door of doom.
    2.Ask the liar-guard to point to the door of doom.
    3.Doesn't matter which one you pick.
(lldb)
```

Is there anyone who could help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly does it stop?

Comment: That is wrong. If you don't know which guard is the liar, how can you ask the liar guard? This problem cannot be well handled with multiple choice, as the solution is obvious once you know it (ask any one guard about what **the other** guard would say is the door to freedom).

Comment: Re your problem: why do you ignore compiler warnings? No surprise if you run into problems if you invoke undefined behaviour ignoring them.

Comment: You've defined two `char answer;` variables, probably not what you intended. Also `char answer = "...";` is a constraint violation; it shouldn't compile at all if you use the proper compile-time options, but you will almost certainly at least get a compile-time warning. Do not ignore warnings from a C compiler; many of them refer to serious problems. At the very least, include the exact text of any warnings in your question. If you're getting compile-time warnings that you don't understand, you're not ready to try running your program.

Comment: Compile with all warning & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`). Improve your code till you get no warnings. Then learn how to use the debugger (e.g. `gdb`) on it

Answer (score 1):

```
 char answer = "No matter which one you choose the guards both tell you which door leads to death, and therefore you can pick the other door.\n";
```

This is certainly wrong. `answer` is a `char` and can hold only a single character not a string literal.

You need to either use `char *` or `char []` and print it with `%s`.

Answer (score 0):

`answer` is a `char` type variable, you can't assign a string to it.

Answer (score 0):

1. `answer` needs to have the type `const char *`.
2. Change `switch (choice) { case 1:` to `switch (choice) { case '1':`

Comment: If you change the type of `answer` (which you should), then the `printf("%c", answer);` calls become invalid; `%c` will need to be changed to `%s`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when the user presses enter to signal that they want to play they are actually sending a second character. Therefore, `choice` gets set to `\n`.

There are a few things to change:

1. `char answer = "...` -> `char answer[] = "...`
2. In the switch put `'` around the numbers (e.g. `1` -> `'1'`)
3. Skip over the newline in choice.

My first thought for number 3 would be something like this:

```
do{
    scanf("%c", &choice);
} while(choice != '1' && choice != '2' && choice != '3');
```

Answer (score 0):

The `printf()` statements in your `switch` section are missing a newline (`\n`). Depending on your terminal, this might cause the output to be hidden. Use: `printf("%c\n", answer);`